# No wireless extensions arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I am having a problem with configuring wifi on Arch. There are completely no wireless extensions. When I run `iwconfig` the result is:

```
lo     no wireless extensions
eno1   no wireless extensions
```

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: iwconfig is depreciated. What do you get when you run _ip -a_? Please post the result in the Question by clicking [edit] instead of clicking [Add Comment] since comments pile up and scroll off the page.

Comment: What is your machine and wireless card hardware? As well as the full output from `ip -a link` and/or iwconfig

Answer (score 2):

First, check if the device has been blocked at start up:

```
rfkill list
```

If so, unblock it:

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

Next, try to find out your wifi device:

```
lspci
```

If you assume the brand of your wifi device, you might go looking for it with grep, e.g.

```
lspci | grep -i broadcom
```

If you found out your wifi device, post it here, so we can do the next steps (loading the correct modules, etc.).

Comment: i run that command i found my device:
***
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
**** what follows?